# Inequalities in mathematics

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ be 8 non negative real numbers such that $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h =16$.
>   If $P= ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fg+gh$ then find the maximum value of $P$.

I tried using rearrangement inequality but couldn't get the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$P\leq(a+c+e+g)(b+d+f+h)\leq\left(\frac{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h}{2}\right)^2=64.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=8$ and $c=d=e=f=g=h=0,$  which says that we got a maximal value.